# Java Extends error - incompatible types

Tags: java, extends, incompatibletypeerror

I am working through my Lecturing class examples, attempting to use extends in java to create an array of different objects. I cant quite explain it so my code is:

`Car` Class:

```
public class Car extends RoadVehicle {
    //single instance variable make
    private String make;

    /**
     * Constructor takes the parameters make
     * which describes the make of car
     */
    public Car (String make, String colour) {
        //sets up initial make 
        super (colour);
        this.make = make;
    }

    /** get the make 
     */
    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return "The colour of the " + make +" is "+ colour;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car1 = new Car ("Ferrari", "Red");
        System.out.println(car1);
        Car car2 = new Car ("Volvo", "Blue");
        car2.addFuel(20);
        System.out.println(car2);
        Car car3 =car2;
        car2.setColour("Green");
        car3.useFuel(10);
        System.out.println(car2);
        System.out.println(car3);
    }
}
```

`Bus` Class:

```
public class Bus extends RoadVehicle {
    private int seats;// number of seats on bus

    public Bus (int seats, String colour) {
        super (colour);
        this.seats = seats;
    }

    public int getSeats () {
        return seats;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return "The " + colour +" bus with "+ seats +" seats.";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bus bus1 = new Bus (10, "Red");
        System.out.println(bus1);
    }
}
```

`RoadVehicle` Class:

```
/** Class to represent the colour and fuel content of the car
 */
public abstract class RoadVehicle {
    protected String colour;
    private int fuel;

    /**
     * Constructor takes the parameters colour and fuel,
     * which describes the car and amount of fuel
     */
    public RoadVehicle(String colour) {
        //sets up initial fuel and colour
        this.colour = colour;
        this.fuel = 0;
    }

    /**
     * Get the colour
     */
    public String getColour () {
        return colour;
    }

    /**
     * get the amount of fuel
     */
    public int getFuel () {
        return fuel;
    }

    /**
     * Change the colour of the car to new colour,
     * there is no check that the string is a sensible car colour
     */
    public void setColour (String newColour){
        colour = newColour;
    }

    /**
     * Chaging the amount of fuel in the car via adding integer
     * We have no check for negative numbers
     */
    public void addFuel (int amount) {
        fuel = fuel + amount;
    }

    /**
     * Change the amount of fuel via subtracting integer
     * We have no check for negative numbers
     */
    public void useFuel(int amount) {
        fuel = fuel - amount;
    }

    /**
     * Show the make and colour of the car, along with fuel remaining
     */
    public abstract String toString ();

}
```

The `GoodsVehicle` class

```
public class GoodsVehicle extends RoadVehicle {
    private int maxWeight;
    private String typeOfVehicle;

    public GoodsVehicle (int maxWeight, String typeOfVehicle, String colour) {
        super (colour);
        this.maxWeight=maxWeight;
        this.typeOfVehicle=typeOfVehicle;
    }

    public int getMaxWeight() {
        return maxWeight;
    }

    public String getVehicleType () {
        return typeOfVehicle;
    }

    public String toString () {
        return colour + " " + typeOfVehicle + " max Weight = " + maxWeight;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GoodsVehicle vechile1 = new GoodsVehicle (10, "van", "Red");
        System.out.println(vechile1);
    }
```

The `TrafficQueue` class then:

```
private RoadVehicle [] Vehicles;
private RoadVehicle [] Cars2;
private static int numberOfCars; //  has to be static for while loop
private String make, colour;

public void add(RoadVehicle car) {
  if(numberOfCars==Vehicles.length) {
     System.out.println("Queue is full! We cannot add any more cars to the Queue!");
     System.exit(1);
  } else {
     Vehicles[numberOfCars] = car;
     numberOfCars ++;
     System.out.println("Car added to queue. Number of cars is:  "  + numberOfCars);

public static void resetNumberOfCars() {
    numberOfCars = 0 ;
}


/**
 * To test the program we have made
 */
public static void main (String [] args) {

   TrafficQueue queue1 = new TrafficQueue(6);

   Car car1 = new Car ("car", "red");
   Car car2 = new Car ("car2", "green");
   Bus bus1 = new Bus (2, "red");
   Bus bus2 = new Bus (3, "green");
   GoodsVehicle vehicle1 = new GoodsVehicle(5, "GoodsVehicle1", "red");
   GoodsVehicle vehicle2 = new GoodsVehicle (5,"GoodsVehicle2", "green");

   queue1.add(car1);
```

In simple terms, I have a `Car`, `Bus` and `RoadVehicle` class. These all extend from another class `Vehicles`. I am creating 2 objects in each of the classes, and then, I am trying to add them to the `TrafficQueue queue1`.

If I just try the above, it gives the following error:

> incompatible types:m Car cannot be converted to RoadVehicle.

The code works fine up until this point, so what is it that I am missing that doesn't allow me to add the differenct `Vehicles` to the `TrafficQueue`?

Comment: Can you please show the respective class definitions (like `class Car extends BLAHBLAH`)? It would help to see the actual inheritance structure

Comment: If `TrafficQueue` expects `RoadVehicle`s make sure that `Car` extends/implements that class/interface.

Comment: The given code doest make it clear why it happens, you probably should add all the classes you´re using here inside the question, or rather it´s relevant parts.

Comment: Could you please provide the car, bus, goods vehicle and road vehicle classes? It's hard to see what you're doing without them.

Comment: Can you please post TrafficQueue code?

Answer (score 0):

Is it just a typo or did you mix up `Vehicle` and `RoadVehicle`?

Yor `Car` class should be declared `public class Car extends RoadVehicle {...}`

Your `TrafficQueue` should have a function `public void add(RoadVehicle v) {...}`

If `Car` indeed extends `Vehicle` and `add()` expects a `RoadVehicle`, it won't work even if `RoadVehicle` extends `Vehicle` since `RoadVehicle` (expected) is more specific than `Vehicle` (provided).

Comment: Sorry guyhs, was struggling to get the code in the correct format!

Comment: The declaration of `Car` is still missing. Does it extend `RoadVehicle`?

Comment: Is the declaration not there? at the top of my `Car` Class?
It extends `RoadVehicle` yes, and within `TrafficQueue` I Can create a new car, as above, and the code compiles.

Comment: Yes, it is there now.

Comment: I can't figure out what the problem is. Perhaps you should clean your code, there are multiple main functions, make sure, you run the correct one. Moreover your question refers to a `Vehicles` class, that I don't expect to exist. Your `

Comment: Your `GoodsVehicle' also extends `RoadVehicle`, doesn't it? Should work as expected...

Comment: My `GoodsVehicle` does extend `RoadVehicle`
sorry about the messiness of the code! I am still trying to neaten it all up!